# How to modify python source code using ubuntu on putty?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, putty

I am now running Ubuntu using putty, and try to modify a Django project using virtualenv. But I don't know how to open the source code.
Please how to open source code and modify
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEhQ2.png)
Thank you

Comment: so you want to modify django or the source of the project which is based on django?

Comment: simple use editor for example `vim` or `none`, but i vote to close your question ` clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need`

Comment: I want to modify python source code settings.py on django.
but I don't know open that file

P.S. I am sorry about short quetion. Because my english is not good..

Comment: Presumably you are connecting to your production server and trying to edit the code there. Don't do this. Clone your project from version control to your local machine, edit it, commit, and push back to production.

Comment: i am using terminal

Comment: Oh, I find it!,, I use vim!!! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either :

- use WinSCP (instead of putty) to edit the files locally, and copy them back to your server
- use a command line editor (such as nano, for something easy, or vim for something more powerful, but less user friendly).